# Can anyone help me achieve these materials (wheel and body color)? I have been trying for hours but no success so far

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

[image: BMWM5CS]

This is the Wheel and Body color combo I have been desperatly trying to recreate, help is appreciated

Comment: show us what you have so far, and we can help you go from there

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like that: First use a *Noise Texture* to give it a grainy texture, push the *Metallic* value up to 1, play a bit with *Specular* and *Roughness*, give it a bit of *Sheen* in order to create a silk effect, and most of all give it *Clearcoat* which is a kind of layer over the surface of the metal:

[image]

Comment: how long do i have to play with Specular and roughness until it works? 10 secs? 1 min? 1 hour? 1 week? i have no idea.... please help!

Comment: it should take between one and ten weeks

Comment: ah ok...then i will come back to you in 9 ½ weeks...thank you for your quick and kind answer!!

Comment: no problem for 9 ½ weeks, and remember, you can leave your hat on!

Comment: Of course I do! Kim loves it‼️‍♂️